# Serre fibration vs Hurewicz fibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibre-bundles

What are the simplest/ typical examples of a Serre fibration which is not a Hurewicz fibration? Is it something pathological?

Sorry if the question is too elementary for MO.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983064/serre-fibrations-vs-hurewicz-fibrations and http://blog.jpolak.org/?p=1449

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A short paper with references to several early counterexamples proves that (in the good category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces) a Serre fibration in which the total space and base space are both CW complexes is necessarily a Hurewicz fibration.

- M. Steinberger and J. West. *Covering homotopy properties of maps between CW complexes or ANRs*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **92** (1984), 573–577, doi:[10.1090/S0002-9939-1984-0760948-6](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1984-0760948-6).

(The proof is corrected in R. Cauty. *Sur les overts des CW-complexes et les fibr'es de Serre*.  Colloquy Math. **63** (1992), 1–7, [link](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/967590)).  No relationship between the covering map and the CW structures is required.  This argues either that counterexamples are
pathological or that it is a special property for the total space of a Serre fibration with CW base space to be a CW complex, although it has the homotopy type of a CW complex if the fiber does.

Answer (score 14):

These show up all the time in various generalized covering space theories, the reason being that you want homotopy lifting with respect to a certain class of spaces that you're interested in (e.g. locally path-connected spaces) which includes all cubes $[0,1]^n$ but probably not *all* spaces.

An important example with a simple construction is the generalized universal covering $p:\widetilde{\mathbb{H}}\to\mathbb{H}$ of the Hawaiian earring $\mathbb{H}$ that I describe in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163847/are-the-higher-homotopy-groups-of-the-hawaiian-earring-trivial/163850#163850). It is characterized by it's lifting property (described in link) which shows it to be a Serre fibration. It is not a Hurewicz fibration since it doesn't have homotopy lifting with respect to non-locally path-connected (even contractible) spaces like $\displaystyle\frac{[0,1]\times\{1,1/2,1/3,...,0\}}{\{0\}\times\{1,1/2,1/3,...,0\}}$.