# CW structure on infinite-dimensional manifolds

Tags: fibration, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, cw-complexes

It is well-known (due to [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938366900024) work of Palais, I believe) that Banach manifolds are dominated by countable CW complexes. It then follows (due Whitehead, as indicated by Milnor in [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-02/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4/) work) that they have the homotopy type of CW complexes.

1. Are there conditions ensuring that a Banach or Fréchet manifold admits a genuine CW complex structure?
2. What are the main examples of that?

Actually, I'm working with Banach fiber bundles, which are Serre fibrations. I would like to regard them as Hurewicz fibrations to use HLP (homotopy lifting property). Due to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/241611) answer of Peter May (and the references cited by him), I know that it is enough to get a CW structure.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: In your application, what are you doing homotopy lifting against? Is it really an arbitrary space, or is there some smoothness requirement?

Comment: I'm trying to use global analysis to get general results ensuring existence of emergence phenomena between parameterized Lagrangian field theories. Those structures appear basically as the space of parameters of the theories. Thus, a priori, they are arbitrary (if we think in finding C^0 emergence phenomena).

Comment: There is a triangulation theorem for Hilbert manifolds (=separable metric spaces locally homeomorphic to $\ell^2$). Namely, any Hilbert manifold is homeomorphic to the product of $\ell^2$ and some locally finite simplicial complex. No smoothness is needed.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems to have some contradiction between the triangulation theorem and Thomas Rot's answer. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: @math-phys-cat: I don't think so. Note that $l^2$ is not a CW complex.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, in your answer (together withe the comments after it) you are suggesting that a Hilbert manifold $M$ cannot admit a CW structure in which there is a point $x\in M$ meeting only finite-dimensional cells. Right?

Comment: No I’m claiming it does not admit a cw structure at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M$ be a Hilbert manifold. Then there exists a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ such that the induced metric $d$ is complete (See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01527.pdf by Biliotti and Mercuri). Thus $M$ has the topology of a complete metric space. By the Baire category theorem $(M,d)$ is a Baire space: It cannot be written as a countable union of closed sets with empty interior.

If $M$ had the structure of a CW complex, it does. It must clearly be an infinite dimensional $CW$-complex, but such a thing is the countable union of its $n$-skeleta, which have empty interior.

With this argument you can treat also other infinite dimensional manifolds: using the fact that seperable Frechet spaces are homeomorphic to seperable Hilbert space, one can show that a Frechet manifold is homeomorphic to a Hilbert manifold.

Comment: maybe I am a bit nitpicking right now, but the n-skeleta of infinite dimensional CW-complexes can in general have nonempty interior. It depends on whether one attaches higher cells to each $n$-cell. This should be the case here, since we look at Banach manifolds.

Comment: @HenrikRüping: Yes, I should argue a bit more about that. I think that if $x$ only meets cells up to a finite dimension, then the local homology $H_*(M,M\setminus \{x\})$ shouldn't vanish. But the local homology of Hilbert manifolds does vanish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the comments.

Comment: Thomas, could you look at my comment below the comment of Igor Belegradek? Thank you.

Comment: This final step (about embedding Fréchet manifolds into Hilbert spaces) is well-known on the separable case. Have you some idea of how to extend this to the general case or if there are obstructions to do that?

Comment: No I don’t know the details about that.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for all the help. I will mark your answer as solving my question.

Comment: @ThomasRot this seems to imply that any (T2) separable Banach manifold is metrizable and hence (by Palais) paracompact. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Overflowian: This seems correct to me.